# How can I align / register two meshes in Open3d? (Python)

Tags: python, registration, mesh, open3d, trimesh

I have two .ply files that contain mesh of objects that are similar in shape. They are initially unaligned. I would like to achieve global registration for the two mesh objects. Is there a way that I can do this without having to initially import the point cloud data, do global registration, and then **re**construct the mesh?

I have tried the steps listed in the open3d documentation (http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.12.0/tutorial/pipelines/global_registration.html) and it works well for the point clouds. However, reconstructing a mesh from the point clouds is challenging, as they are a relatively complex shape, so I would like to avoid that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is you don't need to reconstruct mesh from point cloud.

Mark the data you have as `mesh_a`, `mesh_b`, `pcl_a`, `pcl_b`.

1. if your `pcl_a/b` is extracted directly from `mesh_a/b` or `pcl_a/b` and `mesh_a/b` has the same **Transformation Matrix**, You can simply apply the transformation matrix obtained from the point cloud alignment to the mesh.
2. if your point cloud data has no relations with your mesh data. You can first sample `mesh_a/b` to point cloud and do registration or directly get mesh vertex as point cloud from mesh data. The rest of the work is the same as in case one.

Here are the example of situation two.

```
import copy

import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d


def draw_registration_result(source, target, transformation):
    source_temp = copy.deepcopy(source)
    target_temp = copy.deepcopy(target)
    source_temp.paint_uniform_color([1, 0.706, 0])
    target_temp.paint_uniform_color([0, 0.651, 0.929])
    source_temp.transform(transformation)
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_temp, target_temp])


def preprocess_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size):
    print(":: Downsample with a voxel size %.3f." % voxel_size)
    pcd_down = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size)

    radius_normal = voxel_size * 2
    print(":: Estimate normal with search radius %.3f." % radius_normal)
    pcd_down.estimate_normals(
        o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=radius_normal, max_nn=30))

    radius_feature = voxel_size * 5
    print(":: Compute FPFH feature with search radius %.3f." % radius_feature)
    pcd_fpfh = o3d.pipelines.registration.compute_fpfh_feature(
        pcd_down,
        o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=radius_feature, max_nn=100))
    return pcd_down, pcd_fpfh


def execute_global_registration(source_down, target_down, source_fpfh,
                                target_fpfh, voxel_size):
    distance_threshold = voxel_size * 1.5
    print(":: RANSAC registration on downsampled point clouds.")
    print("   Since the downsampling voxel size is %.3f," % voxel_size)
    print("   we use a liberal distance threshold %.3f." % distance_threshold)
    result = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_ransac_based_on_feature_matching(
        source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh, True,
        distance_threshold,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint(False),
        3, [
            o3d.pipelines.registration.CorrespondenceCheckerBasedOnEdgeLength(
                0.9),
            o3d.pipelines.registration.CorrespondenceCheckerBasedOnDistance(
                distance_threshold)
        ], o3d.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria(100000, 0.999))
    return result


def main():
    voxel_size = 0.01
    print(":: Load two mesh.")
    target_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh('bunny.ply')
    source_mesh = copy.deepcopy(target_mesh)
    source_mesh.rotate(source_mesh.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz((np.pi / 4, 0, np.pi / 4)), center=(0, 0, 0))
    source_mesh.translate((0, 0.05, 0))
    draw_registration_result(target_mesh, source_mesh, np.identity(4))

    print(":: Sample mesh to point cloud")
    target = target_mesh.sample_points_uniformly(1000)
    source = source_mesh.sample_points_uniformly(1000)
    draw_registration_result(source, target, np.identity(4))

    source_down, source_fpfh = preprocess_point_cloud(source, voxel_size)
    target_down, target_fpfh = preprocess_point_cloud(target, voxel_size)
    result_ransac = execute_global_registration(source_down, target_down,
                                                source_fpfh, target_fpfh,
                                                voxel_size)
    print(result_ransac)
    draw_registration_result(source_down, target_down, result_ransac.transformation)
    draw_registration_result(source_mesh, target_mesh, result_ransac.transformation)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Great Answer!  I'm just beginning to learn this library myself.  How would you alter this solution to factor in an object where the scale has also been modified.  So, in your above example, if you not only rotated and translated the cloned model but also applied a scale of 0.5 to x,y,z (shrink by 50%)?  I see you can use TransformationEstimationPointToPoint(True) to factor in scale, however I'm still not able to get the two bunnies to match after applying a scale transformation.

Comment: The problem is the algorithm used to estimate transformation. However, there are some solutions to solve scale, rotate and translate ICP. But it's still a big problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: It is a little late, the problem you want to solve is a 7dof registration problem. As far as I know there are two types solution, one is to use [CPD](https://github.com/neka-nat/probreg), another is to use [OpenGR](https://github.com/STORM-IRIT/OpenGR) which could estimate R, t, s at the same time